# Como calcular a media de desconto no MySQL

Tags: mysql

Preciso calcular a media de desconto por produto na minha tabela no MySQL, porém meu código só esta executando a media, como posso fazer para ele me dar o produto e a media de desconto em cima desse produto ?

código fonte:

```
SELECT avg(desconto) as media from object
```

Comment: Alias, a pergunta do exercicio é essa: Qual o valor médio dos descontos dados por produto. As colunas presentes no resultado da consulta são: ID_PROD, MEDIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Será algo deste género:

```
SELECT      ID_PROD
        ,   AVG(desconto) AS media 
FROM        object 
GROUP BY    ID_PROD
```

Comment: João, eu não tenho a coluna id_prod, ela teria que ser imprimida assim como a media

Comment: Se quer fazer uma média dos descontos por produto tem de ter uma coluna de produto para poder agrupar, caso contrário não consegue! Coloque a estrutura da tabela na sua questão.

Comment: as tabelas são id_nt, id_item, cod_pro, valor_unit`, `quantidade`, `desconto`

Comment: Deu certo, valeu

Comment: De nada! Dê um UP e marque a resposta como correta!